# Pollard's rho algorithm termination

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

[Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) algorithm is a simple probabilistic method for factoring a composite number $N$. There are two parameters one can choose when starting the algorithm: the initial function values $x$ ($0 \le x \le N-1$) and the polynomial (most often just its constant term $b$, where $1 \le b \le N-3$).

Even if one tried all of the parameter values within given ranges, could it still happened that the algorithm would not be find any factors?

Answer (score 1):

The pollard-rho method eventually arrives in a loop, so it is possible that with given parameters , it never finds a factor. The method is called pollard-rho because the letter rho contains a straight line and a circle (in which the method will land unless it finds a factor)

Comment: For example, let's say that for $N=10, x=1, b=2$ it arrives in the loop, ok. If I try with different $x$ and $b$ it will possibly break out of the loop. My question is, for given $N$, could it happen that every combination of $0 \le x \le N-1$ and $1 \le b \le N-3$ will always end up in a loop? Conversely, is it always possible to break out of the loop by choosing different parameters $x$ and $b$?

Comment: What I try to ask is that a loop is detected by $GCD > 1$ but it could also mean $GCD = N$, in which case one could try with different parameters. Will this "restarting" eventually always lead to a factor?

Comment: @EcirHana Do you mean choosing an arbitary other polynomial or a concrete strategy like replacig $x^2+1$ by $x^2+2,x^2+3,x^2+4$ and so on ?

Comment: I was thinking the later, i.e. $x^2+b$. But it's a good question and I assume that there might be some arbitrary polynomial for with it factors but I don't see a systematic way of finding it. Trying $1 \le b \e N-3$ seems much easier.